# Is there a function to calculate the returns on a dataset of many (997) different stocks?

Tags: r, return, stock, price

I'm just starting to get to know R, and I know how to calculate the returns for a single column simply with ((new-old)/old) or with Delt from the quantmod package. However, I have to calculate the returns for each column and create new columns that contain this return. 
My data is structured in the following way:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PuRz.png)

Is there a quick way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with usable data, not a picture and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a function! You are searching for `apply`. With apply you can repeat a function for every row or column in a matrix for example.
In your case it should look like

```
apply(data,2,function)
```

data and function is self explanatory. If you insert a "2" it is done by column, "1" for by row.